# Can you do a "join" in an XML schema

Tags: join, xsd

I'm pretty sure the answer to this is no but it never hurts to ask. Is there a way to do a join in an XML schema?

Here's what I mean. You can have `employees/employee/@office_id` and elsewhere in the xml have `/offices/region/office/@office_id`. Is there a way in the schema to tell it that these two attributes map to each other?

I ask because then we can automatically for an employee get their office info without requiring the user to specify this relationship.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JOIN is a relational concept.  You'd have to code the equivalent in XPATH.  I don't believe there's any mechanism to help you with it.  You'll have to get the office instances and loop over them for a given individual's office, all in your code or XSLT.

Comment: Yep, that we've got. I was wondering if the schema spec had a setting to specify a relationship so we could build that part of the xpath for people.

Comment: That's what I figured - but wanted to make sure. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking if you can set up a schema such that every employee/@office_id has a corresponding office/@office_id?

If you know the possible office ids you could create a type like so:

```
<xsd:simpleType name="OfficeIDType">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:integer"> <!-- or whatever type an office id is -->
        <xsd:enumeration value="1"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="2"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="3"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

And then when declaring your attributes, make them this type and required, like so:

```
<xsd:attribute name="office_id" type="OfficeIDType" use="required"/>
```

Comment: That we already have. It's being able to construct part of the xpath for users if we know the connection. Like how you can automatically build joins in a SQL select from the metadata.

Comment: So are you actually looking for an XPath expression? What does the schema have to do with that?

Comment: No, I'm asking if there is the equivilent of join info in the schema that would allow us to have the program automatically craft that part of the xpath. That's what we do in the case of SQL, read the metadata and automatically build the join part of the select.

Comment: Oh, so you wanted to know if there was a Foreign Key equivalent in xml schema.

Comment: Yes - exactly. If there is a foreign key equivilent in the schema then we can build that part of the xpath automatically.

Answer (score -2):

External references and connections between XML entities can be specified with XLINK.